# Entering Schengen countries with a valid visa which will expire in 10 days

Tags: visas, schengen

I have an Indian passport and a valid two-year multiple-entry Schengen visa which will expire in mid-March 2013. Can I enter the Schengen country a week before it expires for a short trip and exit before it expires?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can enter as long as you will leave the Schengen area before it expires. Make sure to make the return ticket available as they may ask for it at the passport control due to the short visa validity.